# Compress folder using pigz without tar

Tags: linux, windows, compression, zip

pigz, which stands for parallel implementation of gzip, is a fully functional replacement for gzip that exploits multiple processors and multiple cores to the hilt when compressing data.

But this tool is used only to compress a single file.

How i can manage it to compress folders too from source code: 
http://www.zlib.net/pigz/pigz-2.3.3.tar.gz

Or any other idea ... but without using TAR since i want use it too in windows os.

Answer (score 3):

PigZ will only compress single files. You will need to use an archiver to collect the files into a single file.

You can use ZIP with no compression (-0) as an archiver, then pipe the output to PigZ for parallel compression.

Comment: How i can do that on windows for example ? about archiving file from command line and send output to pigz ?

Comment: Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx
Specifically: 
The following command stores files in the cabinet with no compression:

`cabarc –m NONE n mycab.cab <files to arcive>`

Then run pigz on the cab file. Can easily be done in a BATCH file.

Comment: @user2183032: Please, can you closely specify the idea to pipe output of `zip -0` to `pigz -K` to reach the zip archive, which can be open in MS-Windows as virtual folder? I tried many option combiantion, but never got the compatible archive.